# Working with one-to-many model relationship in templates (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models which have a one-to-many relationship:

```
class Book(models.Model):
title= models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField()
source = models.TextField()
source_site = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Chapter(models.Model):
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
chtitle = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
chtitletext = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.chtitle
```

And I am trying to use this in my templates for specific books:

```
    <!-- Placing header with book title is finished! -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var headerText = '{{books.1.title}}'
        placeHeader(headerText);
    });
</script>

{% block chapterheader %}
<script>
    //var chHeader = '{{chapters.0.chtitle}}' + '<br>' + '{{chapters.0.chtitletext}}';
    var chHeader = '{{books.1.chapters.0.chtitle}}' + '<br>' + '{{books.1.chapters.0.chtitletext}}';

    placeChapterHeader(chHeader);
</script>
{% endblock%}
```

The commented out line in block chapterheader works fine in terms of displaying it.  But I need to send a value that has chapter info for a particular book.

```
{% load static %}
{% include 'main/bookDisplay.html' %}

<body>

<!-- Placing header with book title is finished! -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var headerText = '{{books.1}}'
        placeHeader(headerText);
    });
</script>

{% block chapterheader %}
<script>
    // var chHeader = '{{chapters.0.chtitle}}' + '<br>' + '{{chapters.0.chtitletext}}';

    var chHeader = '{{ books.1.chapters.0 }}';
    placeChapterHeader(chHeader);

</script>
{% endblock%}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what 'send a value' means?

Comment: I want to get chapter titles for a particular book and display it in my template.  I can get {{chapters.0.chtitle}} but not the chapter title for a particular book. "send a value" probably wasn't the best way to convey that

Comment: Why are you rendering HTML this way by rendering into **JavaScript** and then rendering using it? (As good as asking to be a victim of XSS) Render HTML normally using [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/).

Comment: @TroyS Can you include the full html file?

Comment: Thanks Abdul.  I will study that.

Comment: Danoram - I will add it as an edit

Comment: Danoram - I changed the line that isn't working.  I need to get the chapter list from book.1 and it looks like I don't have the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste people's time.  I put together a basic website with html/css/jquery. Then I tried to inject it into an empty django project and tried to edit the code line by line to make it work.  It went much better when I started from scratch by creating the Django project first.